# Concept XML XLST preceding-sibling and ancestor

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am very new to xslt, and found it can be easy or complex.
I want to make clear some concepts. 
What is preceding-sibling and what is ancestor, after searching from google, I found ancestor explanation. and the chart from their website makes easier to understand.

But I still don't understand preceding-sibling

```
<product>
    <inventory>
        <drink>
            <lemonade>
                <price>$2.50</price>
                <amount>20</amount>
            </lemonade>
            <pop>
                <price>$1.50</price>
                <amount>10</amount>
            </pop>
        </drink>
          <service>
           <address />
            <phone />
            <delivery> City </delivery>
          </service>      
        <snack>
            <chips>
                <price>$4.50</price>
                <amount>60</amount>
            </chips>
        </snack>
        <hotfood></hotfood>
         <totalprice> $15</totleprice>

    </inventory>
</product>
```

so how do I read this **preceding-sibling::pop/ancestor::inventory/totalprice**

ancestor::inventory/totalprice = product\inventory\totalprice
preceding-sibling::pop - I dont understand this one
then how to read all together?

Many thanks

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## The preceding-sibling:: axis

The `preceding-sibling::` axis is an axis of navigation that includes all the preceding sibling elements to the focus element. By "sibling" we mean a different element which has the same parent to the reference item. By "preceding" we mean a node that occurs before the reference one. The order of the `preceding-sibling` axis is the reverse document order. Take a look at this document:

```
<fruit>
  <banana>
   <lady-finger-banana/>
  </banana> 
  <apple/>
  <pear/>
  <kiwi/>
</fruit>
```

If the focus node is pear, then the sequence `preceding-sibling::*` is ...

1. apple
2. banana

Note: fruit, pear, lady-finger-banana and kiwi are not in the sequence.

So the following is true:

- `preceding-sibling::*[ 1]` is the apple
- `preceding-sibling::*[ 2]` is the banana
- `count( preceding-sibling::*)` is 2
- `preceding-sibling::apple[ 1]` is also the apple
- `preceding-sibling::banana[ 1]` is the banana
- `preceding-sibling::*[ 3]` is absent or the empty sequence

## preceding-sibling::pop/ancestor::inventory/totalprice Example

We have to alter your sample document a little bit to usefully study this example

```
<product>
    <inventory>
        <drink>
            <lemonade>
                <price>$2.50</price>
                <amount>20</amount>
            </lemonade>
            <pop>
                <price>$1.50</price>
                <amount>10</amount>
            </pop>
            <focus-item />
         </drink>
        <totalprice>$15</totalprice>  
    </inventory>
</product>
```

Let us say the focus is on the element focus-item.
To evaluate the expression `preceding-sibling::pop/ancestor::inventory/totalprice` follow these steps:

1. `preceding-sibling::pop` selects all the preceding `pop` elements to focus-item. This evaluates to a sequence of one node.
2. For each item in the left hand sequence (just one `pop` element it so happens), set this item as a temporary focus item, and evaluate the expression of the right of the / operator which is ...

   ```
   ancestor::inventory
   ```

   There is only one such node, which is the ancestral inventory node. Thus the first / operator evaluates to a sequence of one inventory node.
3. Now we evaluate the effect of the second / and its right-hand operand expression total price. For each item in the left hand sequence (just one inventory node so it happens), set this as a temporary focus item and evaluate `totalprice`.
4. `totalprice` is short for `child::totalprice`. There is only one total price element on the child axis of the temporary focus node, so the final result is a sequence of one node, which is the total price node.

## Understanding by Diagrams

Here is a diagram for `preceding-sibling::`. In it the reference node is Charlie and the node on the `preceding-sibling::` axis is in green. It is the only such node.

[image]

Comment: @Sean: If I have the focus on element focus-item: `parent::*` would give me `<drink>`, `ancestor::*`would give me `<drink>`, `<inventory>`and `<product>`. Is that correct? Best regards, Peter (+1 for your nice explanation)

Answer (score 5):

Axes useful for navigation through the node tree. So it depends from your problem what kind of axis is useful.

The following stylesheet illustrates the difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="snack">
        <xsl:variable name="siblings" select="ancestor::node()"/>
        <debug>
        <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::node()">
                <sibling>
                        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                </sibling>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::node()">
                <ancestor>
                        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                </ancestor>
        </xsl:for-each>

        </debug>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Preceding-sibling gets all element siblings that preceded it in the current node level.  Unless you specify one or more of those preceding siblings with an xpath expression.  If you specify a specific preceding-sibling with xpath it always starts with 1 in square brackets.

Ancestor is the first matching ancestor that matches the expression.  So it goes back up the node tree to look at a matching expression based on where you currently are pointing.  So if you were at product/inventory/drink/pop  or just /pop then ancestor inventory/totalprice just looks for the frist occurence and it should only return back a pointer to point to that matching case else it will be pointing to nothing and you'll still be pointing at pop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. could I please get a bit more examples?